# Counting number of string occurrences in repeated sampling

Tags: r, string, counter

I'm trying to complete a computational genetics homework problem. I need to count the number of times the dinucleotide "AA" appears when my known nucleotide frequencies (A, T, C, G) are all 0.25 and I sample a 1000 character long string 1000 times. Ultimately, to determine the frequency of the "AA" dinucleotide.

```
SeqLength <- 1000
Nreps <- 1000
x <- c("A", "T", "C", "G")
pi <- c(rep(0.25, 4))
counter <- 0

for (i in 1:Nreps){
    X <- sample(x, SeqLength, replace=TRUE, pi)
    for (j in 1:X - 1){
        if (j == "AA"){
            counter <- counter + 1
        }
    }
}
counter / Nreps
```

I obtain the following error and warnings. They all make sense, I'm just not sure how to go about resolving them.

```
Error in 1:X : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In 1:X : numerical expression has 1000 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:X : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I can't seem to translate what I want to do in my head to functioning code. Any help/guidance/lessons is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: If your `X` is `AAA`, do you have one `AA` or two `AA`?

Comment: Good question. Let's say 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach. You can use `replicate` to perform the sampling `Nreps` number of times. For each sampled sequence, you check if the nucleotide in each position and the position following it is `"A"` and sum the resulting logical to get the count.

```r
SeqLength <- 1000
Nreps <- 1000
x <- c("A", "T", "C", "G")
pi <- c(rep(0.25, 4))
counter <- 0

set.seed(42)
seqs = replicate(n = Nreps,
                 expr = sample(x = x, size = SeqLength, replace = TRUE, prob = pi),
                 simplify = FALSE)
counts = sapply(seqs, function(s){
    sum((s[-1] == "A") & (s[-length(s)] == "A"))
})
mean(counts)
#> [1] 62.321
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! I understand everything you explained above. The only part I'm curious about is why use 42 for set.seed ?

Comment: Got it. Thank you!